# ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! when using .loc or .set_index after adding a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, valueerror

I am trying to add a different index to a multi index df.

My df looks like this:

```
Sample                0                                            \
Axis                  x                                             
Frequency  4.000014      8.000028      12.000042     16.000056      
0          4.897566e-07  2.929368e-07  1.351820e-07  1.053036e-07   

Sample                                                             \
Axis                                                                
Frequency  20.000069     24.000083     28.000097     32.000111      
0          1.671902e-07  3.119009e-07  3.956999e-07  4.163999e-07   

Sample                                 ...             1                \
Axis                                   ...             z                 
Frequency  36.000125     40.000139     ...  39964.138764  39968.138778   
0          4.206877e-07  2.951226e-07  ...  2.530015e-09  2.370161e-09   

Sample                                                             \
Axis                                                                
Frequency  39972.138792  39976.138806  39980.138820  39984.138834   
0          1.675662e-09  1.432578e-09  9.210665e-10  9.327703e-10   

Sample                                                             
Axis                                                               
Frequency  39988.138848  39992.138862  39996.138875  40000.138889  
0          1.895297e-09  3.678412e-09  3.743124e-09  1.758966e-09  

[1 rows x 60000 columns]
```

It has the levels: "Sample","Axis" and "Frequency"

To add a different Index i added a new column to the existing df with:
`row.loc[:,("Index")] = (1)`.

Adding the new column works fine and i can still display my df.

When i now try to set the index to this column with:
`row.set_index("Index")`
I get the `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`.

I tried to add a column with a Key on each level: `row.loc[:,('Indexx',"q","w")] = (1)`
and tried to set this as Index and got the same result.

I also noticed that after adding the new column using .loc like this: `row.loc[:,(0,"y")]` doesnt work anymore and i get the same error Message.

I dont get the error Message as far as i can tell the Index is unique, it cant be not unique since in this example the df has only one row.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing wrong is creating an index column with all values = to 1. Instead create the index with a different value in each row ie: 1,2,3 instead of 1,1,1 like you currently are doing.

To just create an index try using: `df = df.reset_index()`

You can also use something like:

```
df['new_indexcol'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, i really appreciate it.
But my df only has one row in this example and i still get the error.